# Sentencia en sql para un datetime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo este fragmento de cogigo

```
public List<byte[]> selectAlarmas1(int numero)
        {
            try
            {
                cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = PRUEBA; Initial Catalog = FUCS; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = admin; Password = 1234");
                cn.Open();
                Console.Write("conectado bien");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write("no se conecto" + e);
            }
            byte[] Datos = null;
            List<byte[]> numeros = new List<byte[]>();
            try
            {
                if (numero == 1)
                {
                    String cama = TextBox1.Text;
                    String Hora = HoraGrafica1.Text;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=" + cama+ "AND OccurTime='"+Hora+"';", cn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
```

Yo en el en la variable que dice `Hora` le asigno algo de esta forma "2009/10/10 09:23" y necesito que me traiga todos los datos de la base de datos que esten entre 09:23:00 hasta 09:23:59 pero con esta sentencia solo toma uno quisiera saber como debo hacer la sentencia para traerlos todos
Gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

te sugiero considerar parametrizar tus valores en la petición a la base de datos, así como reestructurizar tu try catch. Te dejo un ejemplo con el uso de [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/yh598w02.aspx) para que dispongas del objeto de tu conexión al finalizar de usarla:

```
public List<byte[]> selectAlarmas1(int numero)
    {

        string connectionString="Data Source = PRUEBA; Initial Catalog = FUCS; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = admin; Password = 1234";
        byte[] Datos = null;
        List<byte[]> numeros = new List<byte[]>();
        if (numero == 1)
        {
            string cama = TextBox1.Text;
            string Hora = HoraGrafica1.Text;
            string query= "Select ECG1 From dbo.Alarm where PatientiID=@cama AND OccurTime between @horaInicio and @horaFin ;";
        }
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                command.Parameters.Add("@cama", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                command.Parameters.Add("@horaInicio", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                command.Parameters.Add("@horaFin", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                command.Parameters["@cama"].Value = cama;
                command.Parameters["@horaInicio"].Value = DateTime.Parse(HoraGrafica1.Text); //aquí tomaría el segundo 0
                command.Parameters["@horaFin"].Value =  DateTime.Parse(HoraGrafica1.Text).AddSeconds(59);//Le agregué 59 segundos

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    Console.Write("no se conecto" + ex.Message);
                }
            }
    }
```

Debes considerar que en tu base de datos también se esté guardando con segundos, de otra manera lo anterior con la 2da linea de tiempo no es necesaria.